Select cell then highlight cells with matching text
I'm trying to click on a cell with text then search a column to highlight any cell that has the same text.
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
    
        .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        
        Select Case Target.Address
        
            Case "$N$6"
                '.Range("B3:L3").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                row_num = 2
                Count = 0
                Do
                    DoEvents
                    row_num = row_num + 1
                    text_review = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:I8" & row_num)
                    If InStr(text_review, text_review) > 0 Then
                        text_review.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        Count = Count
                    End If
                Loop Until text_review = ""
                
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

On
If InStr(text_review, text_review) > 0 Then

I get

Run-time error '13'
Type mismatch


text_review = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I2:I8" & row_num) note when (eg) row_num is 3 that would be I2:I83 which is probably not what you wanted...    In any case you really want text_review = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row_num, "I").Value

...but there are other errors too.  See my suggestion below.

What's the formula in N6?

Try something like this:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v, c As Range, rng As Range
    
    If Target.Address <> "$N$6" Then Exit Sub
    
    v = Trim(Target.Value) 'the value of the seelcted cell
    
    'cells to check for `v`
    'In the worksheet code module `Me` refers to the sheet
    Set rng = Me.Range("I2", Me.Cells(Me.Rows.count, "I").End(xlUp))
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'clear previous
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'nothing to look for
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        'check for case-insensitive match
        If InStr(1, c.Value, v, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub

